# Detect when click on div starts and when it ends in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

How can i detect when the click on a div starts or when it ends with something like

```
$('#mydiv').on("clickstart",function(){
    //Do stuff
});

$('#mydiv').on("clickend",function(){
    //Do stuff
});
```

Comment: add some more detail.. what exactly you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be:

```
$('#mydiv').on("mousedown",function(){
    //Do stuff
});

$('#mydiv').on("mouseup",function(){
    //Do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't think there are any event like click start or click end.
However you can handle this mouse events.
Actually below is the sample you need to try.

**Click:**

```
$( "#target" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

**MouseDown:**

```
$( "#target" ).mousedown(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .mousedown() called." );
});
```

**MouseUp:**

```
$( "#target" ).mouseup(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .mouseup() called." );
});
```

Hope this will help you :)